# React routes in spring boot app causing 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, tomcat, react-router

I have a Spring boot application that loads a react.js application in src/main/resources/static under bundle.js and index.html.

The following 4 routes render with no issues:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Users} />
  <Route exact path="/create" component={UserCreate} />
  <Route exact path="/creategolfevent" component={CreateGolfEvent} />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/eventleaderboard"
    component={EventLeaderBoard}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/createcompetition"
    component={CreateCompetition}
  />
</Switch>
```

But these two routes dont:

```
<Route exact path="/scorecardview/:id" component={ScoreCard} />
<Route exact path="/update/:id" component={UserUpdate} />
```

The above 2 routes cause a 404. It appears anything under react `"/*/ *"`is not rendered to react but anything under `"/*"` is.

My controllers are mapped in Spring using:

```
/competition
/events
/golfcourses
/golfleaderboard
/holes
/players
/scorecard
/scores
```

Under each on of those are various `/{id}` mappings `*/other/`.  Why are those two routes not being rendered in react?

Comment: The server should be configured to return the root index.html file for *all* page requests into the app.

Comment: I have added this:     public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
             registry.addViewController("/**")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
            }    And that didn't work so I also tried a catch all requestmapping("/**") that didn't work either
  I even put both in and ended up in a recursive call leading to stackoverflow error